# How to pass a function name to be tested to unit test.TestCase?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to test two almost identical functions, and don't see much point copy-pasting the tests that I have written for `function1`. Can I somehow pass the function name to a class derived from `unittest.TestCase` and set up the function that needs to be tested in `setUp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no trick to this. Functions are first-class objects in Python and can be passed around just like any other parameter. So this would work, assuming the functions under test are 'func_one' and 'func_two':

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def generic_test(self, func):
        result = func()
        ... assertions about result....

    def test_func_one(self):
        self.generic_test(func_one)

    def test_func_two(self):
        self.generic_test(func_two)
```